# Hashtable size said to be arbitrary, why?

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap, hashtable

I am learning about abstract data types [here](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/Hashing.html#implementing-the-map-abstract-data-type). Lately I have been reading about hashing with a Map (or some data structure like a dict).

Here is how the code looks like:

```
class HashTable:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 11
        self.slots = [None] * self.size
        self.data = [None] * self.size

def put(self,key,data):
  hashvalue = self.hashfunction(key,len(self.slots))

  if self.slots[hashvalue] == None:
    self.slots[hashvalue] = key
    self.data[hashvalue] = data
  else:
    if self.slots[hashvalue] == key:
      self.data[hashvalue] = data  #replace
    else:
      nextslot = self.rehash(hashvalue,len(self.slots))
      while self.slots[nextslot] != None and \
                      self.slots[nextslot] != key:
        nextslot = self.rehash(nextslot,len(self.slots))

      if self.slots[nextslot] == None:
        self.slots[nextslot]=key
        self.data[nextslot]=data
      else:
        self.data[nextslot] = data #replace

def hashfunction(self,key,size):
     return key%size

def rehash(self,oldhash,size):
    return (oldhash+1)%size

def get(self,key):
  startslot = self.hashfunction(key,len(self.slots))

  data = None
  stop = False
  found = False
  position = startslot
  while self.slots[position] != None and  \
                       not found and not stop:
     if self.slots[position] == key:
       found = True
       data = self.data[position]
     else:
       position=self.rehash(position,len(self.slots))
       if position == startslot:
           stop = True
  return data

def __getitem__(self,key):
    return self.get(key)

def __setitem__(self,key,data):
    self.put(key,data)
```

Now within the textbook, the author states that the size of the hashtable is arbitrary. See here:

> Note that the initial size for the hash table has been chosen to be
>   11. Although this is arbitrary, it is important that the size be a prime number so that the collision resolution algorithm can be as
>   efficient as possible.

Why is this arbitrary? It would seem that the number of slots given is directly correlated to how many values can be stored. I know that other hashtables may be flexible and be able to store more data into one data slot, but in **THIS** specific example, it isn't just 'arbitrary'. It is exactly how many values can be stored.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think this is intended to be sort of a "minimal hash" - this is about the least you could do and still have something you could call a hash function. Clearly, you could extend this by adding some code for example to resize the hash if it gets full (or more likely, if the load gets too high). This would probably be a very good exercise for you to attempt.

Comment: Its not about the size of what is stored in the HashTable, I think i refers to making simple hash functions. For this prime numbers are used, e.g. [here](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/classes/hmc.cs070.200101/homework10/hashfuncs.html).

Comment: Thanks for confirming how basic this is. I think my basic knowledge of how hashtables work is limited, thereby making it confusing. It would seem though, that making a table with a bigger prime number would allow for you to have more available slots and require less need for you to rehash, and have less items to search through in each slot (if you extended the data slots to hold more than one value). The items would be spread thinner in general. Is this not correct?

Comment: you do know there is a `hash` function in python which will take an arbritary number of of arguments and return a hash value of all the arguments.

Comment: @ApathyBear You seem to be confused about what "rehashing" means. Generally, hash tables allow a fixed occupation ratio, e. g. 2/3 or something like that. So, if you have e. g. a hash table with 11 slots, it can contain 7 values before it is resized. When the 11-slot table with 7 values is instructed to insert an 8th value, then it allocates a bigger table (e. g. one with 19 slots), re-computes the hash and the slot index of each old entry, moves the old entries from the old table to the new one, inserts the one new entry into the new table, then deallocates the old table. …

Comment: @ApathyBear … This is the process which is called rehashing, and it is repeated multiple times as the table size grows.

Comment: Thank you. That really helped. I think the book I am reading is a bit incomplete or perhaps meant to be a general introduction.

Comment: To clear things up: Rehashing is when you hash an element in a different context. The most common reason to do this is that you've resized the table, so you have to rehash all the elements to find their new buckets. But you _can_ also use rehashing for probing: instead of modifying the hash value, you modify the original element and rehash it. Your linear probing is technically rehashing (because your hash value is just `%size`, so adding 1 to the hash value is the same as adding 1 to the original element mod `size`), but I don't think most people would see it that way, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is this arbitrary?

Because he could have chosen any other small prime.

> It would seem that the number of slots is directly correlated with […] how many values can be stored

Yep, and that's irrelevant. If you need to grow your hash table, you resize (reallocate) and re-hash it. This is not what's the author is talking about.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one more concern that I commented on in my OP. If you could please elaborate on that, that would help me out a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[The Paramagnetic Croiss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27456720/908494) answered your main question. The number 11 does of course mean that you can't fit more than 11 elements without reallocating your table and rehashing all your elements, so obviously it's not arbitrary in *that* sense. But it's arbitrary in the sense that as long as the number is prime (and, yes, larger than the number of inserts you're going to do), everything the author intends to demonstrate will work out the same.*

<sub>* In particular, if your elements are natural numbers, and your table size is prime, and small enough compared to the largest integer, `% size` makes a great hash function.</sub>

But for your followup question:

> It would seem though, that making a table with a bigger prime number would allow for you to have more available slots and require less need for you to rehash, and have less items to search through in each slot (if you extended the data slots to hold more than one value). The items would be spread thinner in general. Is this not correct?

If I understand you right, you're not using the right words, which is why you're getting confusing answers. Your example code uses a function called `rehash`, but that's misleading. Rehashing is one way to do probing, but it's not the way you're doing it; you're just doing a combination of linear probing and double hashing.* More commonly, when people talk about rehashing, they're talking about what you do after you grow the hash table and have to rehash every value from the old table into the new one.

<sub>* When your hash function is as simple as `key%size`, the distinction is ambiguous…</sub>

Anyway, yes, more load (if you have N elements in M buckets, you have N/M load) means more probing, which is bad. To take the most extreme element, at load 1.0, the average operation will have to probe through half the table to find the right bucket, making the hash table as inefficient as brute-force searching an array.

However, as you decrease load, the returns drop off pretty fast. You can draw the exact curve for any particular hash implementation, but the rule of thumb you usually use (for closed hashes like this) is that getting the load below 2/3 is usually not worth it. And keep in mind that a larger hash table has costs as well as benefits. Let's say you're on a 32-bit machine with a 64-byte cache line. So, 11 pointers fit in a single cache line; after any hash operation, the next one is guaranteed to be a cache hit. But 17 pointers are split across two cache lines; after any hash operation, the next one only has a 50% chance of being a cache hit.*

<sub>* Of course realistically there's plenty of room inside your loop to use up 2 cache lines for a hash table; that's why people don't usually worry about performance at all when N is in single digits… But you can see how with larger hash tables, keeping too much empty space an mean more L1 cache misses, more L2 cache misses, in the worst case even more VM page misses.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Well, nobody can predict the future, as you never know how many values the data structure user will actually put in the container.
So you start with something small, not to eat too much memory, and then increase and rehash as needed.